# How I can get a mongoose schema from a model keystone? (or how I can generate a mongoose schema from a collection)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, keystonejs

I want to connect keystone to another app that ask for a mongoose schema.

How I can get a mongoose schema from a model keystone? (or how I can generate a mongoose schema from a collection)

Comment: Are you trying to figure out how to expose your Keystone schema within a NodeJS route, or are you trying to work inside of another schema and effectively plug your Keystone schema into an existing MongoDB schema?

Answer (score 0):

I just found that you can use the schema of a Keystone list like this:

```
var User = new List('User')
User.schema // Use this for the mongoose model
```

Comment: That doesn't give you access to the actual Keystone `User` list, though. It just instantiates a new one in its place, which might not be what you want.